# How to presist state change in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a reactjs app which uses redux for state management. But I got into some issue here. In the `productDetailpage.js` I have a `add To Cart` button when user clicks on it add product to the cart and the `add to cart` changes to `add to cart`. But the problem comes when user goes to any other product it already shows `added to cart`. We need to refresh to make it `add to cart` again.

Here is my code

> ProductDetail/BottomDrawer.js

```
 <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Button
                      disableRipple={true}
                      className="btn"
                      variant="outlined"
                      onClick={addToCart}
                    >
                      {addedToCart ? "Added To Cart" : "Add To Cart"}
                    </Button>
                  </Grid>
```

> addToCartActions.js

```
export function addToCart(product, quantity) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TO_CART_LOAD"
    });
    new _rest()
      .post(URLConstants.urls.ADD_TO_CART, {
        optionVariationId: null,
        productId: product.productId,
        quantity: quantity
      })
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: "ADD_TO_CART_SUCCESS",
          payload: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return dispatch({
          type: "ADD_TO_CART_ERROR",
          payload: error
        });
      });
  };
}
```

> addToCartReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  loaded: false,
  error: null,
  itemsInCart: null,
  pagination: null,
  totalamount: 0,
  checkedItems: [],
  paymentStatus: "NIL_TRANSACTION",
  order: {
    addressId: "NIL",
    paymentType: "NIL"
  },
  bulkOrderData: []
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_CART_LOAD":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };

    case "ADD_TO_CART_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        loaded: true,
        addedToCart: action.payload
      };

    case "ADD_TO_CART_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.error
      };
```

Comment: I suggest that problem is all add-to-cart  buttons share the same "added or not" state. So, for example, id 1 product been added and change state from "not added" to "added", then other buttons also share "added" state.  So, the "added or not" state should add another property to ref which production is added. When state change, button check the added id, if not itself, then remain "add to cart", if id matches ,then change to "added to cart."

Comment: `{addedToCart ? "Added To Cart" : "Add To Cart"}` You need to check for productId here if it is already added on the cart.

Comment: Can you ever have more than a single item in your cart? Your reducer appears to only allow for single item in cart. If this is by-design then Sarthak's suggestion is the one. If not, then perhaps you should store them in an array and update the array of "added cart items" as they are added/removed from the car, *and* do the id check Sarthak suggests.

Comment: @DrewReese I am trying to go with checking id .